# Using few specific fields from another

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

So I was trying to use this fields on my Insuree model which originally came from Policy model

```
policy_category = models.ForeignKey('Policy', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True,null=True,default="Life")
policy_length = models.ForeignKey('Policy', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True, default="")
coverage_amount = models.ForeignKey('Policy', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

However, I was encountering these errors:

[image: Error]

What I was trying to do is make a POST endpoint with policy_length, policy_category, and coverage_amount.
[image]

Now, I'm not sure if its possible the thing I was trying to do. Any possible approach?

Comment: Can you explain what exactly you are trying to do here?

Comment: I want to make an endpoint that includes policy_category, policy_length, and coverage amount but I can't seem to use them at once

Comment: can you post you whole model code

Comment: what do you want to do or what is problem make clear.

Answer (score 0):

Try Using related_name while using multiple foreign key as In db table it collides with related name.

```
 policy_category = models.ForeignKey('Policy', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True,null=True,default="Life")
 policy_length = models.ForeignKey('Policy', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True, default="", related_name ='policy_length ')
 coverage_amount = models.ForeignKey('Policy', on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name ='coverage_amount  ')
```